# Complex equations: NDSolveValue / FEM,

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

So, I am trying to solve a simple problem using the FEM method.

The distribution of Voltage over a region,

The region is,

```
  << NDSolve`FEM`
bm = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {12/10, 0.}, {12/10, 1.}, {1., 
      1.}, {0., 1.}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        5}, {5, 6}, {6, 1}, {5, 2}}]}];
em = ToElementMesh[bm, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{0.5, 0.5}, 1}, {{1.2, 0.5}, 2}}];
```

which look like this,

```
     Show[{
  em["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[EdgeForm[Red], Thin],
     "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]],
  bm["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> Black]]
  }, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

I have two equations,

```
op1 = Laplacian[v1[x, y], {x, y}];
op2= Laplacian[v2[x, y], {x, y}];

bc1=DirichletCondition[v1[x, y] == 4, x == 12/10 && y==1];
bc2=DirichletCondition[v2[x, y] == 0, x == 0];

omg=376.991;
dd=100;
d=25*10^-6;

 eef={4.18382,4.22462,9.95342,12.8216,13.9473,14.4967,14.8028,14.9896,15.1113,15.195,15.2551,15.2998,15.3341,15.3611,15.3829,15.4007,15.4155,15.428,15.4387,15.4478,15.4556,15.4624,15.4682,15.4733,15.4777};
    ee1 = ListInterpolation[eef, {{0, Length[eef] - 1}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

ee1 has dependence on v1[x,y]-v2[x,y], as `ee1[Abs[v1[x,y]-v2[x,y]]]`

```
{v1fun,v2fun} = NDSolveValue[{op1==If[ElementMarker == 1, ((I omg ee1[
     Abs[v1[x, y] - v2[x, y]]])/(dd d)) (v1[x, y] - 
     v2[x, y]), 0], op2==If[ElementMarker == 1, (
   (I omg ee1[
     Abs[v1[x, y] - v2[x, y]]])/(dd d)) (v2[x, y] - 
     v1[x, y]), 0],bc1,bc2},{v1[x, y],v2{x,y}}, {x, y} ∈ em]
```

The output contour plot of (Abs[v1[x,y]-v2[x,y]]) should be the distribution of voltage over the entire mesh region with the highest values at the x=0 and x=1.2.

I am getting different errors in versions 11.1 and 13.1. I am trying to solve complex equations in NdSolveValue and FEM.

Comment: I think the main problem is that it is not possible to find the derivative of the Abs of complex values. The derivative is needed for linearization. Maybe you can replace the Abs with a smooth function for which a derivative can be found.

Comment: @user21 Thanks! I will follow the suggestion. However, the answer given below is also very close to solution. That could be an another way as well.

Comment: Absolutely, I just wanted to express that I am not convinced that the reason is the large numbers, it's a mathematical problem, I think.

Comment: Btw. I added code such that you will not see the Part message any longer (but you will see the other messages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter `k = omg/dd/d` of this model is about 150796, together with function `ee1` it gives about 10^7 on the right side `op1` and `op2`. It is too high for nonlinear FEM, why `NDSolve` failed on this example. But the problem could be solved with linear FEM. Therefore we use the false transition method as follows

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
bm = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {12/10, 0.}, {12/10, 
      1.}, {1., 1.}, {0., 1.}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        5}, {5, 6}, {6, 1}, {5, 2}}]}];
em = ToElementMesh[bm, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{0.5, 0.5}, 1}, {{1.2, 0.5}, 2}}];

op1 = Laplacian[v1[x, y], {x, y}];
op2 = Laplacian[v2[x, y], {x, y}];

bc1 = DirichletCondition[v1[x, y] == 4, x == 12/10 && y == 1];
bc2 = DirichletCondition[v2[x, y] == 0, x == 0];

omg = 376.991;
dd = 100;
d = 25*10^-6;

eef = {4.18382, 4.22462, 9.95342, 12.8216, 13.9473, 14.4967, 14.8028, 
   14.9896, 15.1113, 15.195, 15.2551, 15.2998, 15.3341, 15.3611, 
   15.3829, 15.4007, 15.4155, 15.428, 15.4387, 15.4478, 15.4556, 
   15.4624, 15.4682, 15.4733, 15.4777};
ee1 = ListInterpolation[eef, {{0, Length[eef] - 1}}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1];
k = omg/dd/d

V1[0][x_, y_] := 4; V2[0][x_, y_] := 0;

Do[{V1[i], V2[i]} = 
   NDSolveValue[{op1 == 
      If[ElementMarker == 
        1, ((I k ee1[Abs[V1[i - 1][x, y] - V2[i - 1][x, y]]])) (v1[x, 
           y] - v2[x, y]), 0], 
     op2 == If[
       ElementMarker == 
        1, ((I  k ee1[Abs[V1[i - 1][x, y] - V2[i - 1][x, y]]])) (v2[x,
            y] - v1[x, y]), 0], bc1, bc2}, {v1, 
     v2}, {x, y} \[Element] em];, {i, 5}]
```

Visualization on every step shows stable solution at `i>2`

```
Table[{DensityPlot[Abs[V1[i][x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] em, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "v1"], 
  DensityPlot[Abs[V2[i][x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] em, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "v2"]}, {i, 5}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Update 1. With `bc2 = DirichletCondition[v2[x, y] == 0, x == 0&& y==0]` we have pictures
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thanks!! In the problem, V1=4 is at the right up corner of the mesh and V2=0 is at the left down corner of the mesh. However, in density plots, both V1 and V2 at the right up corner. V2 should be at the opposite side of the V1.

Comment: @a019 Do you mean that your `bc2=DirichletCondition[v2[x, y] == 0, x == 0]` is wrong and it should be `bc2=DirichletCondition[v2[x, y] == 0, x == 0&&y==0]`?

Comment: Yes, I thought x==0  will be enough, however it should be bc2=DirichletCondition[v2[x, y] == 0, x == 0&&y==0]

Comment: @a019 See update to my answer.